# How can I inspect the shadow DOM of native controls in Chrome developer tools?

Tags: css, google-chrome, shadow-dom, developer-tools

I want to style a native input element, which in Chrome [has a shadow root](https://javascript.info/shadow-dom) and [can be styled with many pseudo-selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/WebKit_Extensions#pseudo-elements). It is apparently possible to see the shadow root in Developer Tools, and [I'm told it looks like this](https://javascript.info/shadow-dom):

[image: range input with shadow root]

However, I cannot see this shadow root (in Chrome 118). **How do I view the shadow root in developer tools?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Developer Tools settings with:

[image]

.

But you can not style `#shadow-root (user-agent)` shadowDOM
created by the **"Browser" Web Components**:

[image]

like you can `#shadow-root (open)` or `#shadow-root (closed)`
created by **"User" Web Components**:

[image]