# How to locate element which is placed inside several shadow-roots using JavaScript Selenium (on Reddit)

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have a node.js script that scrapes a reddit page in order to extract some information.

In this scenario the url is the following:      "https://www.reddit.com/avatar/shop/product/storefront_nft_01HMZYP9FM37N9ZWVD8C1V9RFH";

and I want to extract the title, identified by the selector: "#avatar-modal > div > div > div._modalWrapper_17eu9_1._modalWrapper_ebsul_1 > div > div > div._panel_yzcdf_210 > div > div._header_1xo8p_69 > h3";

The expected result is "Black Background".

Here's the script:

```
async function scrapeReddit() {
    const url =
        "https://www.reddit.com/avatar/shop/product/storefront_nft_01HMZYP9FM37N9ZWVD8C1V9RFH";

    const cssSelector =
        "#avatar-modal > div > div > div._modalWrapper_17eu9_1._modalWrapper_ebsul_1 > div > div > div._panel_yzcdf_210 > div > div._header_1xo8p_69 > h3";

    const driver = new Builder()
        .forBrowser("chrome")
        //.setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options().headless())
        .build();

    try {
        await driver.get(url);

        await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css(cssSelector)), 10000);

        const textElement = await driver.findElement(By.css(cssSelector));
        const text = await priceElement.getText();

        console.log("title:", text);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
    } finally {
        await driver.quit();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the scirpt start the browser and load the website, even though the element I'm looking for is visible, the function `until.elementLocated` timeout after 10 seconds.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is placed inside several shadow-roots, to get internal shadow root structure, you should get it's host first and then get `shadowRoot` property.

In your case you can write function that drills inside several shadow-roots in browser context.

1. 1st level shadow-root has tag `shop-flow-manager`
2. 2nd level has tag `pdp-partial-generator`
3. 3rd level has tag `product-detail-card-view`
4. And your target element with text Black Background has tag `h3`

`drillIntoShadowDoms` function gets internal element from several hosts (and waits for each host to be rendered) and can be used inside JS executor.

Then you just call this function, using `By.js(script, ...args)`

More about [shadow-root](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM)

```js
const drillIntoShadowDoms = async (hostsSelectors, targetSelector) => {
  let waitFor = async (action, timeoutMs = 10000, pollIntervalMs = 500) => {
    let isTimeout = false;
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      isTimeout = true;
    }, timeoutMs);
    let result;
    while (!isTimeout && !result) {
      result = await action();
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, pollIntervalMs));
    }

    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    if (isTimeout) {
      throw new Error('Timeout exceeded!');
    } else {
      return result;
    }
  };

  async function drillIntoShadowRoots(hostsSelectors, targetSelector) {
    let targetElement;
    const elementGetter = s => (targetElement ?? document).querySelector(s).shadowRoot;
    for (const selector of hostsSelectors) {
      targetElement = await waitFor(() => elementGetter(selector));
    }
    return waitFor(() => targetElement.querySelector(targetSelector));
  }

  return drillIntoShadowRoots(hostsSelectors, targetSelector);
};

const driver = new Builder()
  .forBrowser('chrome')
  .build();

const url = 'https://www.reddit.com/avatar/shop/product/storefront_nft_01HMZYP9FM37N9ZWVD8C1V9RFH';
await driver.get(url);

const productName = await driver.findElement(By.js(drillIntoShadowDoms, ['shop-flow-manager', 'pdp-partial-generator', 'product-detail-card-view'], 'h3'));
console.log(await productName.getText());
```

Comment: Hey can I ask you something? How did you visualise the shadow dom elements? I have the "show user agent shadow DOM" flag active in my chrome inspector settings but still I can't see any shadow element when inspecting that page...!

Comment: @ste https://monosnap.com/file/AAB1VfCKyEQdaKeHe3CKmVw9tgLYBH - look this video. `shadow-root (open)` is actually shadow dom. Arrow down means that it's one of the part of path to your element. Element which is placed near opened `shadow-root (open)` is it's shadow host

Comment: Thanks for the video! Even with the option open (https://monosnap.com/file/pJas3IfhYAGUtjkAkB6vCiLQWLC3qQ) I don't see the shadow-root elements, this is what I see when I inspect the element: https://monosnap.com/file/O7zCD867mDHuHGBf7ALMTvylp1G2rh

Even the class names are different...

Comment: @ste have you tried to enable preference of Elements tab from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77336695/how-can-i-inspect-the-shadow-dom-of-native-controls-in-chrome-developer-tools ?

Comment: Yes, I think I did, if you check the first screenshot that I attached to my previous comment, I'll copy it here: https://monosnap.com/file/pJas3IfhYAGUtjkAkB6vCiLQWLC3qQ
That's the option that should show the shadow-root element, right?
Also, if you check the second screenshot and compare it to your video, even the class names of the elements are different and I can't understand why!

Comment: @ste log off your account and you will see them. DOM for logged in user and logged off is different) As far as you don't log in Reddit, you have shadow-doms (that is their rendering logic)

Comment: True! You have been incredibly helpful, thank you so much!