# Convert Object to WebElement or SearchContext JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

What is the correct way of converting an Object to WebElement or SearchContext using JavaScript?

In Java, I was able to convert or cast successfully just by adding "(WebElement)" or "(SearchContext)", but when I did the same steps in JavaScript using "as Webelement" or "as SearchContext", I am getting an error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext
```

This is also related in Shadow Root.

Code in Java:

```
webElemHost = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//tagHere[@id='idHere']"));
strCSSSelector = "#idHere";
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) browser;
SearchContext shadowRoot = (SearchContext) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", webElemHost);
WebElement shadowContent = shadowRoot.findElement(By.cssSelector(strCSSSelector));
```

Code in JavaScript (Not Working):

```
webElemHost = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//tagHere[@id='idHere']"));
strCSSSelector = "#idHere";
var JavascriptExecutor js = browser as JavascriptExecutor;
var SearchContext shadowRoot = js.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", webElemHost) as SearchContext; <== ERROR HERE
var WebElement shadowContent = shadowRoot.findElement(By.cssSelector(strCSSSelector));
```

Note that I cannot use getShadowRoot function of findElement due to restrictions in Selenium Version (limited to v3)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript (not TypeScript), there is no casting there, so you are going in wrong direction.

Instead of this, you can get target element instance inside js executor by calling `querySelector` inside.

Also, it's JS, so element getters are executed `async`, so you should `await`for `Promise` to be resolved.

[Similar question reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78009638/how-to-locate-element-which-is-placed-inside-several-shadow-roots-using-javascri/78011986#78011986)

Example on Reddit shadow-root structure:

```js
const url = "https://www.reddit.com/avatar/shop/product/storefront_nft_01HMZYP9FM37N9ZWVD8C1V9RFH";
await driver.get(url);
const shadowHostElement = await driver.findElement(By.tagName('shop-flow-manager'));
let shadowHost = await driver.findElement(By.js("return arguments[0].shadowRoot.querySelector(arguments[1])", shadowHostElement, 'pdp-partial-generator'));
```